# FTP client, Unexpected error occurred on a receive occurs twice, then times out indefinitely

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I have an FTP client, running as part of a windows service that gets information from an FTP server on a scheduled basis. My issue is that sometimes, the FTP server is down for planned maintanance. When this happens, my FTP client still calls out on a scheduled basis and fails with the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive
```

I get the error above **twice**. After this, I get the following timeout error every time indefinitely:

`System.Net.WebException The operation has timed out`

Even with the maintenance window complete, my windows service will keep timing out when attempting to connect to the FTP server. The only way we can solve the problem is by restarting the windows service. The following code shows my FTP client code:

```
var _request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(configuration.Url);
    _request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    _request.KeepAlive = false;
    _request.Timeout = configuration.RequestTimeoutInMilliseconds;
    _request.Proxy = null;  // Do NOT use a proxy
    _request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(configuration.UserName, configuration.Password);

_request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = configuration.RequestTimeoutInMilliseconds;
_request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = configuration.RequestTimeoutInMilliseconds;

try
{
    using (var _response = (FtpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse())
    using (var _responseStream = _response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var _streamReader = new StreamReader(_responseStream))
    {
        this.c_rateSourceData = _streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception genericException)
{
    throw genericException;
}
```

Anyone know what the issue might be?